# What do the 68 group symbols in KeePassX stand for in detail?

Tags: 12.04, security, documentation, keepass

KeePassX 0.4.3 > Menu > Groups > Add New Group > (Group Preferences) >  '>' lists 68 group symbols. What do these 68 group symbols stand for in detail? The KeePassX handbook does not explain that. I could not find the answer in the documentation of the keepassx project either.

Answer (score 2):

They are icons you can choose from to associate to the group you are creating. No hidden meaning intended, I think.

The icon will be shown near the name of the group in the groups' list on the left of the main window.

Comment: enzotib: You say: "No hidden meaning intended, I think." I would like to challenge this. If there is no (hidden) meaning intended, then it is almost useless.